# one Routing with multiple components

Tags: angular, routes

**Question:**
How do I define 2 components for one route?

My website looks something like the picture below. The White boxes are static and never change, the left and right ones always change depending on what route I go to.

```
http://myapp.com/route
```

this should show route-left.component and route-right.component. Whereas:

```
http://myapp.com/another
```

should show another-left.component and another-right.component.

I have been trying to find a solution but no luck. I know that Router picks the first route and only gets that one Component. Not sure how to do 2 components. My current code is:

Router.module.ts

```ts
import { RouteLeftComponent } from '...';
import { RouteRightComponent } from '...';
import { AnotherLeftComponent } from '...';
import { AnotherRightComponent } from '...';
// import Your Canvas View

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', redirectTo: '/router', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: 'router', component: RouteRightComponent},
    {path: 'router', component: RouteLeftComponent, outlet="sidebar"},
    {path: 'another', component: AnotherRightComponent},
    {path: 'another', component: AnotherLeftComponent, outlet="sidebar"},
]
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      RouteRightComponent,
      RouteLeftComponent,
      AnotherRightComponent,
      AnotherLeftComponent
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ],
    imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  })
export class RoutingComponent {}
```

the html file just has:

```html
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
...
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

cheers for help

[image]

Comment: Can you explain more detail.

Comment: Probably you need to route them as a children routes of your parent component. Within the parent component you can have children routes.